# Relationship between surface tension coefficient and the mass diffusion coefficient

Tags: fluid-dynamics, surface-tension, diffusion

For two incompressible, isothermal, Newtonian fluids in contact (at very low Reynolds numbers) what is the quantitative relationship between their surface tension coefficient and their mass diffusion coefficient ?

Comment: Why would there be a relationship?

Comment: Do you understand what thermal diffusivity actually is?

Comment: Experiment: In a test-tube fill some dyed water (surface tension is 72mN/m) and pour some heptane (surface tension is 20mN/m) over it. Put a stopper over the test-tube and check back after a month - would you spot any dyed water blobs within the heptane due to mass diffusion ?

Comment: You wouldn't spot any blobs, but you would probably spot a gradational  change in color.

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking of the [Marangoni effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marangoni_effect)? While surface tension has no relation to molecular diffusion, a gradient in surface tension may result in mass transfer across a fluid interface.